# How to positioning specific sheet on Excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vb.net, worksheet

folks...
I need a help with C# and Microsoft Excel.

All my classes are working fine for what I need, but now I have to positioning on a specifically Sheet of my Workbook.

All my base classes are in C#, but I use this on vb:

```
    Private Shared app As NSCExcelApp
    Private Shared wb As WorkBook
    Private Shared ws As WorkSheet


    Public Shared Sub Simulate(_total As Double, _nameSheet As String)

        If (IsNothing(app)) Then
            app = New NSCExcelApp()
            app.Visible = true
            wb = app.OpenWorkbook(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, nameFileEXCEL))
        End If

        wb.ActiveSheet

        ws.Range("C2:C2".Select()
        app.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _totalToString("N2")
```

When I use wb.ActiveSheet, I can get the activesheet (the first one of my .xlsx).

But, how can I get another sheet?

Theses are my classes:

```
  public class NSCExcelApp : Object
    {
        public Type ExcelType { get; set; }
        private object obj;

        public NSCExcelApp()
        {
            Type ExcelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
            obj = Activator.CreateInstance(ExcelType);
        }

        public NSCExcelApp(object obj)
        {
            this.obj = obj;
        }

        public WorkBook AddWorkBook()
        {
            object w = this.Workbooks;
            return new WorkBook(w.GetType().InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, w, new object[] { -4167 }));
        }

        public WorkBook OpenWorkbook(string fileName)
        {
            return new WorkBook(Workbooks.GetType().InvokeMember("Open", 
                                                                 BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, 
                                                                 Workbooks , new object[1] { fileName }));
        }

        private object Workbooks
        {
            get
            {
                return obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Workbooks", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj, null);
            }
        }
```

and I have the WorkBook class, and the WorkSheet class:

```
    public class WorkBook
    {
        Type WorkBookType { get; set; }
        object obj;

        public WorkBook(object obj)
        {
            WorkBookType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Workbook");
            this.obj = obj;
        }


        public WorkSheet ActiveSheet
        {
            get
            {
                return new WorkSheet(obj.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveSheet", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj, new object[] { }));
            }
            set
            {
                obj.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveSheet", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj, new object[] { value.obj });
            }
        }


        public WorkSheet Sheets(int index)
        {
            object o = obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Sheets", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj, new object[] { });


            PropertyInfo[] x = o.GetType().GetProperties();

            o = o.GetType().InvokeMember("Item", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, obj, new object[1] { index });
            return new WorkSheet(o);
        }



    }
```

```
    public class WorkSheet
    {
        public object obj { get; set; }

        public WorkSheet(object obj)
        {
            this.obj = obj;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the sheet you want: (edited for VB instead of C#, sorry)

VB:

ws = wb.Worksheets("mysheetname")

C#:

ws = wb.Worksheets["mysheetname"];

Replace "mysheetname" with whatever the name of the sheet is that you need, like "Sheet1".

Comment: It doesn´t worked... when I use it, it returns "Worksheets is not a member of NSCExcelWorker.WorkBook'

Comment: I see now. Why aren't you using the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" assembly to do this? I should have read your code beyond the VB part. It seems like you could save yourself a lot of work by just referencing the Excel interop, which already has all of those C# classes built in. Is there a reason you are not doing that, or did you just not know about it?

Comment: I just received the project that way, tho I can make changes, if necessary.

Comment: But, using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" assembly may occur any errors on my customer? Could we have problems if the customer use an older version or a newest one than mine of Microsoft Office?

Comment: If your customer has Office installed and you code it properly it will work fine, but that is a larger discussion. If you intend to stick with what you have, I can't help. Sorry. Best of luck.